# Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS while changing ViewControllers

Tags: objective-c, ios

I needed to chance my ViewControllers, so I used this function:

```
(void)pushViewFromRight:(UIViewController*)coming over:(UIViewController*)going {
    CGRect frameComing = coming.view.frame;
    CGRect frameGoing = going.view.frame;
    frameComing.origin.x = 0;
    frameComing.origin.y = -460;
    coming.view.frame = frameComing;
    if ([coming.view superview] == nil)
        [SlideContainer addSubview:coming.view];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"frame" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

    [coming viewWillAppear:YES];
    [going viewWillAppear:YES];
    frameComing.origin.y = 0;
    coming.view.frame = frameComing;
    going.view.frame = frameGoing;
    [going viewDidDisappear:YES];
    [coming viewDidAppear:YES];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

On the Second ViewController I created a button to go back.
But when I want to go back, (even if there are no actions after pressing the button), it crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
Why does this happen?

Comment: You probably should not be calling viewWillAppear and viewDidDisappear in an UIView animation.  Why exactly are you doing that?

Comment: It's a samples from Apple Developers forum, so I used that

Comment: Are you retaining your UIButton, or is it an ivar?

Comment: I deleted viewWillAppear and viewDidDisappear, nothing has changed

Comment: Another button is in the second .xib

Comment: You are either not retaining your button or your viewController. If you added your button through the .xib then it most likely is your VC.